# cannot deploy a smart contract since 'Shapella' Shanghai Upgrade

Tags: remix, gas

I am no longer able to deploy the same exact smart contracts since Shapella, (WITH OPTIMIZATIONS), that I was able to deploy with no problem at all. Is anyone else facing a similar issue?

I get "contract creation code storage out of gas" error message and "max fee per gas less than block base fee". And I may not have the necessary gas fee in the wallet at the moment, but I still think you should see something like your metamask prompt load up and then tells me that I do not have enough in my wallet to pay the gas fee.

I am doing this on the web version of the latest remix IDE btw.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the `maxFeePerGas` in you tx. You submitted it with less than the baseFee, so nodes will reject it to mitigate DoS attacks.